# Identifying a story about boy with no memory of his past

Tags: story-identification, books

This is a book which I partially read around 5 years ago, about a boy around teen age, who I believe has escaped from somewhere (probably some sort of facility) and has no memory of his past.

The only scene I can remember is him running away through a town and stealing some clothes from a washing line. Which he later learns are designer clothes when the victim's mother is interviewed in the news (not sure which media).

I also believe that he ends up hiding in some sort of an abandoned house, which ends up getting set on fire by the folk who are trying to re-capture him.

Comment: What precisely is science-fiction or fantasy about this story?